# UDP checksum calculation not working with newer version of gcc

Tags: c, strict-aliasing

The code included below is a stripped-down implementation of a function that generates a UDP packet for a given fixed-size payload and sends it.

After switching to a newer version of gcc this code suddenly shows an error: the UDP checksum is not calculated correctly, and this can be traced down to the line

```
pseudoHeader->protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;
```

for which the compiler seemingly does not generate an instruction if at least `-O2` optimization is used.

The following workarounds resolve the issue (each suggestion works independently, i.e. you do not to have to apply all of them at once!):

- move the mentioned line before the two calls to `inet_pton`
- remove the call to `memset(ipHeader, 0, sizeof(struct ip))` after the checksum calculation
- make `ip_checksum()` an external function outside of this translation unit

The fact that the code makes heavy use of casting together with the error only appearing for `-O2` or higher and the nature of the workarounds virtually calls for this to be an aliasing error in the code. Is there an actual error and if so, how can it be fixed?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/udp.h>
#include <netpacket/packet.h>

#define UDP_PORT 2345
#define REPLY_PAYLOAD_SIZE 360

typedef struct UDPPseudoHeader
{
    unsigned long int source_ip;
    unsigned long int dest_ip;
    unsigned char reserved;
    unsigned char protocol;
    unsigned short int udp_length;
} UDPPseudoHeader;

void sendPacket(unsigned char* packet, int len);

static unsigned short ip_checksum(unsigned short *ptr, int len)
{
    int sum = 0;
    unsigned short answer = 0;
    unsigned short *w = ptr;
    int nleft = len;

    while(nleft > 1) {
        sum += *w++;
        nleft -= 2;
    }

    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xFFFF);
    sum += (sum >> 16);
    answer = ~sum;
    return(answer);
}

void sendBroadcastPacket(uint16_t destPort, char* packet) {
    unsigned char buffer[REPLY_PAYLOAD_SIZE + sizeof(struct ip) + sizeof(struct udphdr)];
    int bufferLen = REPLY_PAYLOAD_SIZE + sizeof(struct ip) + sizeof(struct udphdr);

    /* initialize header pointers */
    struct udphdr* udpHeader = (struct udphdr*)(buffer + sizeof(struct ip));
    UDPPseudoHeader* pseudoHeader = (UDPPseudoHeader*)(buffer + sizeof(struct ip) - sizeof(UDPPseudoHeader));
    struct ip* ipHeader = (struct ip*)(buffer);

    memset(buffer, 0, bufferLen);

    /* copy user data */
    memcpy(buffer + sizeof(struct ip) + sizeof(struct udphdr), packet, REPLY_PAYLOAD_SIZE);

    /* fill in UDP header */
    udpHeader->source = htons(UDP_PORT);
    udpHeader->dest = htons(destPort);
    udpHeader->len = htons(sizeof(struct udphdr) + REPLY_PAYLOAD_SIZE);
    udpHeader->check = 0;

    /* create UDP pseudo header for checksum calculation */
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "0.0.0.0", &pseudoHeader->source_ip);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "255.255.255.255", &pseudoHeader->dest_ip);
    pseudoHeader->reserved = 0;
    pseudoHeader->protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;
    pseudoHeader->udp_length = htons(sizeof(struct udphdr) + REPLY_PAYLOAD_SIZE);

    /* calculate UDP checksum */
    udpHeader->check = ip_checksum((unsigned short*) pseudoHeader, bufferLen - sizeof(struct ip) + sizeof(UDPPseudoHeader));

    /* fill in IP header */
    memset(ipHeader, 0, sizeof(struct ip));
    ipHeader->ip_v = 4;
    ipHeader->ip_hl = 5;
    ipHeader->ip_tos = IPTOS_LOWDELAY;
    ipHeader->ip_len = htons(bufferLen);
    ipHeader->ip_off = htons(IP_DF);
    ipHeader->ip_id = 0;
    ipHeader->ip_ttl = 16;
    ipHeader->ip_p = IPPROTO_UDP;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "0.0.0.0", &ipHeader->ip_src);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "255.255.255.255", &ipHeader->ip_dst);
    ipHeader->ip_sum = 0;

    /* calculate IP checksum */
    ipHeader->ip_sum = ip_checksum((unsigned short*) ipHeader, ipHeader->ip_hl * 4);

    sendPacket(buffer, bufferLen);
}
```

Comment: That's some seriously brittle code... Ideally this should work to/from raw byte streams and copy to/from the struct (and fix endianess while at it) without the dirty casts. In the present code everything is copied anyway, so it wouldn't affect performance.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. This is in use for almost a decade now, so I was surprised that it was not working anymore all of a sudden. Well, it turned out I was just lucky before. While writing down the question I was obviously searching in the right direction so that I could finally give the answer myself.

Comment: @ChristophFreundl In `ip_checksum()`, `int sum = 0;` as `unsigned sum = 0;` avoids issues when `len` is large.  Sign shifting in `sum >> 16` is the concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code indeed violates the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule). The compiler assumes that the call to `ip_checksum()` does not depend on the assignments to the struct members `reserved` and `protocol` because these modify `char`s and `ip_checksum()` is calculated over an array of `unsigned short`s. Therefore the assignments are completely optimized away since the following call to `memset()` overwrites the memory anyway.

A possible solution is to declare the pseudo header as

```
typedef union {
    struct {
        unsigned long int source_ip;
        unsigned long int dest_ip;
        unsigned char reserved;
        unsigned char protocol;
        unsigned short int udp_length;
    } hdr;
    unsigned short as_short[6];
} UDPPseudoHeader;
```

and replace the generation of the pseudo header and the checksum calculation by

```
/* create UDP pseudo header for checksum calculation */
inet_pton(AF_INET, "0.0.0.0", &pseudoHeader->hdr.source_ip);
inet_pton(AF_INET, "255.255.255.255", &pseudoHeader->hdr.dest_ip);
pseudoHeader->hdr.reserved = 0;
pseudoHeader->hdr.protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;
pseudoHeader->hdr.udp_length = htons(sizeof(struct udphdr) + REPLY_PAYLOAD_SIZE);

/* calculate UDP checksum */
udpHeader->check = ip_checksum(pseudoHeader->as_short, bufferLen - sizeof(struct ip) + sizeof(UDPPseudoHeader));
```

Comment: I strongly recommend to use `stdint.h` instead. Some weird compiler ports make `long` 8 bytes on 64 bit computers, in which case you end up with bloat overhead bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Another  issue:

**Alignment**

```
unsigned char buffer[REPLY_PAYLOAD_SIZE + sizeof(struct ip) + sizeof(struct udphdr)];
...
struct ip* ipHeader = (struct ip*)(buffer);
```

`buffer` is not certainly aligned for a `struct ip`.

Comment: That is a good remark. I will extend the approach of creating a suitable struct/union to the whole buffer which should take care of the proper alignment, also I can get rid of pretty much all casts that way.

Comment: @ChristophFreundl A _cast_ is often a sign of doing something wrong and best avoided - exceptions exist.